# r code for calculating Probability of not cyan

Tags: r

```
cyan <- 3
magenta <- 5
yellow <- 7
p <- cyan/ (cyan + magenta + yellow)
```

My r code calculates the probability that a random draw of balls will be cyan at 0.2
How to use the p variable to calculate the probability that cyan will not be drawn ?

Comment: this is is exercise 2 in [this book chapter](https://rafalab.github.io/dsbook/discrete-probability.html)

Comment: at least change the color names

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for the compliment of 0.2?  Here are two versions:

```
marble_count           <- cyan + magenta + yellow
probabiliy_cyan        <- cyan / marble_count
probabiliy_cyan_not_v1 <- (marble_count - cyan) / marble_count
probabiliy_cyan_not_v2 <- 1 - p_cyan
```

results:

```
> p_cyan
[1] 0.2
> p_cyan_not_v1
[1] 0.8
> p_cyan_not_v2
[1] 0.8
```

*edit*: I wouldn't call it a [*p*-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value), because people might think that hypothesis testing is involved.  Assuming the marbles are equally weighted, this is just a proportion/probability.